# How to add if statement in do-while loop without the program being exited?

Tags: java

I have 2 classes. This program simulates a ATM pretty much. The user will ask either to deposit, withdraw, or view the balance of the users bank account.

The balance would be set to zero at first then the user can deposit or withdraw money.

The first class which is called `CheckingAccount` will have the methods and no main method while the `TestCheckingAccount` has the main method. All the inputs and outputs will occur in the `TestCheckingAccount` class while the `CheckingAccount` does the calculations.

If the user picks to deposit then the balance of the account will be added to the amount the user wants to deposit to his/her account. The `getBalance` method in the `CheckingAccount` class returns the balance of the users account while the `processDeposit` adds the amount the user wants to the deposit to the balance while `processCheck` decreases the amount the user picks to the balance.

If the user chooses to view the balance then it will print the users balance.

## CheckingAccount class

```
public class CheckingAccount{
    double myBalance = 0;

    public double getBalance(){
        return myBalance;
    }

    public void processDeposit(double amount){
        myBalance += amount;
    }

    public void processCheck(double amount){
        myBalance -= amount;
    }
}
```

## TestCheckingAccount class

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestCheckingAccount {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CheckingAccount check = new CheckingAccount();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String choice;
    double moneyAdded;
    double moneySubtracted;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("Deposit");
        System.out.println("Withdraw");
        System.out.println("Balance");
        System.out.println("Exit");
        System.out.println("**********************************************");
        System.out.println("Which operation would you like to use?");
        choice = in.nextLine();

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Deposit"))
        {
            System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
            moneyAdded = in.nextDouble();
            check.processDeposit(moneyAdded);
        }

        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Withdraw"))
        {
            System.out.println("How much money would you like to withdraw?");
            moneySubtracted = in.nextDouble();

            check.processCheck(moneySubtracted);
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Balance"))
        {
            System.out.printf("$%.2f%n" , check.myBalance);
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }
    while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Deposit")||choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Withdraw")||choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Balance"));

    in.close();

}
```

}

The program runs fine but the issue that I am having is that the the program must ask the user if he/she wants to deposit, withdraw, or view the balance until the user is done and exits the program.

So the part when the program asks the user if she/he wants to deposit, withdraw, or view the balance in the account must be in a loop. I put it inside a do-while loop. So when I run the program and ask for the balance is prints out the balance and then loops fine and then the programs ask again if he/she wants to withdraw, deposit, view the balance, or exit.

But when I ask the program to withdraw or deposit then it runs but does not loop but instead exits the loop.

How am I able to make the program so that it can withdraw  or deposit money but still loop and go back to the menu where it asks the user if he/she wants to deposit or withdraw money and not just end the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an infinite loop and `break` on the "Exit" condition. Also, you can use a [`try-with-resources` close statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to close your `Scanner`. Something like,

```
try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {      
  String choice;
  double moneyAdded;
  double moneySubtracted;

  while (true) {
    System.out.println("Deposit");
    System.out.println("Withdraw");
    System.out.println("Balance");
    System.out.println("Exit");
    System.out.println("**********************************************");
    System.out.println("Which operation would you like to use?");
    choice = in.nextLine();

    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Deposit")) {
      System.out.println("How much money would you like to deposit?");
      moneyAdded = in.nextDouble();
      check.processDeposit(moneyAdded);
    } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Withdraw")) {
      System.out.println("How much money would you like to withdraw?");
      moneySubtracted = in.nextDouble();
      check.processCheck(moneySubtracted);
    } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Balance")) {
      System.out.printf("$%.2f%n", check.myBalance);
    } else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Scanner's next method instead of nextLine.

```
choice = in.next();
```

The nextDouble does not take the last newline character into consideration and therefore it is left for the nextLine method instead. This means that the nextLine with read a line break next time it is asking the user for input (Empty input). Since the input does not match the requirement for the do loop to continue, the program will exit.

I hope that the answer helps you.

Answer (score 2):

What is happening I think is that it is reading a blank line after it has read a double, and that is not being checked for in the `while` condition. To help you learn you should put a break point or some debug and check this.

However it would be easier to just specify when you want to *exit* the loop using a not (`!`), rather than when you want to stay in it, this means you do not need to [repeat the comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) of the option strings:

```
do
{
   ... //this will repeat until they type Exit
}
while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"));
```

You would then also remove the code:

```
//else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit"))
//{
//    System.exit(0);
//}
```